# trying to decode @ into whitespace

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, decoding

```
origAlpha = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits  + string.punctuation + ''

shift = int(input("what shift do you want to use to decode? "))
shiftAlpha = origAlpha[shift : ] + origAlpha[ : shift]
messageToDecode = 'k@nkmg@rtqitcookpi'
decodedMessage = ""
count = 0
while count < len(messageToDecode):
  nextLetter = messageToDecode[count]
  if(nextLetter=='@'):
      decodedMessage += ' '
      
  elif nextLetter.isalpha():
      index = shiftAlpha.index(nextLetter)
      nextLetter = origAlpha[index]
  decodedMessage += nextLetter
  count += 1
```

im trying to decode the @ into whitespaces but its not working and cant seem to figure out the error can someone help- shift is 2 - i get this answer 'i@like@programming' when i want it 'i like pogramming'

Comment: `messageToDecode = "k@nkmg@rtqitcookpi"` - the value should be quoted else it is considered to be a variable. Also, this variable name is not allowed.

Comment: Can you more specifically state what _"it's not working"_ means for you?

Comment: i get this answer 'i@like@programming' when i want it 'i like pogramming'

Comment: how should the variable name be like- im new to programming ?

Comment: `count` stays at 0 forever. This code isn't going to do what you want *or* what you say it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're including digits and punctuation in your `origAlpha` and `shiftAlpha`, even though you're checking for `nextLetter.isalpha()`, and digits and punctuation aren't alphabetic characters. That said, you unconditionally add `nextLetter` to `decodedMessage`. To make sure no `@` characters get added, you can do something like this:

```
  nextLetter = messageToDecode[count]
  if nextLetter == '@':
      nextLetter = ' '
  elif nextLetter.isalpha():
      index = shiftAlpha.index(nextLetter)
      nextLetter = origAlpha[index]
  decodedMessage += nextLetter
```

Bonus:

Instead of using `origAlpha` and `shiftAlpha` to find a string in linear time, consider using a dictionary, and instead of using a `while` loop, consider using a `for` loop. You can get something like this:

```
origAlpha = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.punctuation

shift = int(input("what shift do you want to use to decode? "))
shiftAlpha = origAlpha[shift:] + origAlpha[:shift]

mapping_characters = dict(zip(shiftAlpha, origAlpha))
mapping_characters['@'] = ' '

message_to_decode = 'k@nkmg@rtqitcookpi'
decoded_message = ""
for letter in message_to_decode:
    decoded_message += mapping_characters.get(letter, letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but can you just use:

```
message = 'k@nkmg@rtqitcookpi'
decoded = message.replace('@', ' ')
```